# How to do Azure Video Watermarking / Overlay

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Can anyone please guide me, step by step how to watermark/Overlay a video in Azure as I am new to Azure. If Possible please guide me with a tutorial or Video tutorial for the same. I have uploaded a .mp4 video in Azure and streamed it and able to view it in azure media player. Please guide me for watermarking or overlaying a video in azure.

Also I need to understand, azure is providing watermarking / overlay as a service so is there a way to do water marking directly with an Azure interface without visual studio C# coding.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to overlay an image onto a video? Or do you want to overlay a video over another video? For the former case, the image will have to overlaid on the input video during the encoding process. There is a basic example documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-advanced-encoding-with-mes#overlay). In that example, the output contains a single MP4 at 640x360 resolution, which is sufficient for delivery via progressive download. Since you need to stream your video, you should update the Codecs section in that example with additional video bitrates - such as the one showed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-mes-preset-h264-multiple-bitrate-720p).

You also mention needing to do this without writing code. If you have a PC, then you can install and run AMS Explorer (https://aka.ms/amse). Browse to the input video you want to process, hit "Ctl+R" and you will see tabs to specify the encoding settings, and others for advanced features including overlays.

Comment: Thankyou for the guidance, i have gone through the above Microsoft Azure tutorial link. i wanted to know if we have any direct way to add image on a video (ie - watermarking the video) without coding in Azure.

Comment: Hi, i installed AMS Explorer and tried overlaying video but it showing following error..
Unhangeled exception has occured in a componenet in your application.
Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject